# How to get expiry date from cookies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, python-requests, setcookie

I am trying to parse the cookies from a website set by the `Set-Cookie` header for their expiry period. I am using the requests library and this is how far I've progressed:

```
import requests

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
if req.cookies:
    for cook in req.cookies:
        if cook.expires: # checking the expires flag
            print('Cookie Expiry Time: %s' % (cook.expires))
```

However, `cook.expires` returns a value incomprehendible, something like `2181183994` and `1550035594`. What needs to be done next to get the exact date time value from the expires flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cook.expires` value you're getting is a timestamp value. You just need to use `fromtimestamp()` from the `datetime` library to resolve this. Here is your code:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
if req.cookies:
   for cook in req.cookies:
       if cook.expires: # checking the expires flag
           print(datetime.fromtimestamp(cook.expires))
```

For example, if your url is `https://github.com`, you get it in the human readable format:

```
2039-02-13 10:30:14 # expiry date for first cookie
2019-02-13 11:30:14 # expiry date for second cookie
```